# Disable Close votes if no more votes possible

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-dialog

If I don't have any more votes to close a question, the dialog should be disabled or at least show the information more visible.

At the moment I can browse through the windows, write a text why I want to close the question and then I get an error message that I have no votes left. I think it is not a good usability.

The dialog or at least the options should be disabled, or a dialog should show that I don't have any votes left.

(Sorry, I cannot add screenshots because of an error in SO or [Imgur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur).)

Comment: Disabling the dialog would be a bad choice, as there is information there that some people might want. The dialog explicitly states how many close votes you have remaining. Why is that not sufficient?

Comment: If the issue is that you don't see the notice that you have no remaining close votes, then a more reasonable solution would be to ask for that information in the dialog to have styling applied which makes it more obvious.

Comment: As I wrote , if you do not look at it and choose the option *Other - add a comment* write your comment, then you get a message, you have no more votes is very anouying

Comment: *have styling applied which makes it more obvious.* Maybe also this one, or disable checkboxes in the last child, if you can't select them.

Comment: Yes, that's annoying, but you *choose* to not look at the information that you have no remaining close-votes, which *is* provided to you *within the dialog*. Again, a more reasonable change would be to ask for the style of the notice, once you have no remaining close-votes for the day, to be more noticeable and different from what it is when it's just telling you the number of remaining votes which you have. It's reasonable to want the information you need to be more clear. It's not a good solution, IMO, to disable functionality other people use, because you're not seeing a piece of info.

Comment: I don't know how many reviewers choose to not look to the remaining votes counter, but I think that there should not be too many. Better to put dev time on other feature requests that will benefited a larger user base.

Answer (score 11):

On the bottom right of the close dialogue it already does tell you how many votes you have left today.

If you've closed a lot of questions today just keep checking that so you know if you're close to running out.

The dialogue is still useful if you're out of close votes because

1. It tells you that you've run out
2. You can see what close votes a question already has

Comment: Yes i know, but I will not look at it every time